# Plotting balls of the Diestel-Leader graphs

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, graph-theory

*(I'm sorry if the question involves too much Mathematics, that's the bane of Mathematical programmation !)*

My goal is to visualize finite radii balls in the Diestel-Leader graph *DL*(*p*,*q*). [Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0403320.pdf) is an article by W. Woess which describes *with pictures* the construction (starting from page 3). I will however give it here with less mathematics to capture the idea.

It is constructed by taking two infinite trees *T<sub>p</sub>* and *T<sub>q</sub>*, each of respective valence *p+1* and *q+1*. We consider height functions *h*:*T<sub>p</sub>→**Z*** and *h':T<sub>q</sub>→**Z***, meaning that each vertex *x* with height *k* has exactly one parent vertex with height *k-1* and exactly *p* (resp. *q*) children with height *k+1*.

Now, the vertex set of *DL*(*p*,*q*) is defined to be {(*x*,*y*)∈*T<sub>p</sub>×T<sub>q</sub>* : *h*(*x*)+*h*'(*y*)=0}, and two vertices (*x*,*y*) and (*x*',*y*') are adjacent in *DL*(*p*,*q*) if and only if *x* and *x*' are adjacent in *T<sub>p</sub>* and *y* and *y*' are adjacent in *T<sub>q</sub>*.

It turns out *DL*(*p*,*q*) is *not* a tree ! Balls whose radii are greater than 4 always have non-contractible loops.

I am fixing arbitrary elements *o*∈*T<sub>p</sub>* and *o*'∈*T<sub>q</sub>* whose heights are zero, and I am willing to plot the sub-graph of *DL*(*p*,*q*) consisting of elements whose distance to (*o*,*o*') is at most a certain radius *R* (that is the ball of radius *R*). This means that I must find all elements of distance at most *R* to *o* in *T<sub>p</sub>*, and of distance at most *R* to *o*' in *T<sub>q</sub>*, and then somehow get the adjacencies between couples of such vertices.

Also, I am mainly concerned about the case *p*=2 and *q*=3, that is *DL*(2,3). However, an algorithm in the general case would be more than welcome !

---

So far, I first tried finding a representation for elements in *T<sub>p</sub>*. I tried implementing the representation given in the paragraph **(2.1) Tree and sequences.** in the article I linked, but even that seemed doomed. Then, I thought about taking a vertex at height *-R*, and represent all its children up to the generation *R* (that is, I would have *2R+1* generations of vertices). To represent a child of a vertex, this corresponds to labelling all the downwards edges with an integer from 0 to *p*-1. I first used a `dec2base` conversion algorithm :

```
def dec2base(x,b):
    if(x==0): return "0"
    digits = []
    while(x>0):
        x,r = divmod(x,b)
        digits.append(str(r))
    return "".join(reversed(digits))
```

Then, I simply looped through all possibles lists, and stored all vertices in a list :

```
def Tree(p,R):
    vertices = []
    for h in range(2*R+1):
        for k in range(p**h):
            vertices.append((dec2base(k,p),h-R))
    return vertices
```

This returns a list of elements of the form `("1201",-1)`, where the string is the path to take from the vertex at height *-R*, and the integer is the height. of the vertex. However, there are two issues :

- **I am generating too many vertices.** Vertices generated by this method are distant at most 2*R*+1 to the origin, but it can happen that they are distant more than *R*.
- **This doesn't generate adjacencies.** In structures like the one presented in [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/visualize-graphs-in-python/) blog article, we need to feed adjacencies, but I think with this method, it's easier to generate an adjacency function (where you feed two vertices and it tells you whether they are adjacent or not) rather than a list of all such values (*i.e.* an adjacency matrix for instance).

With this in mind, I find it even harder to then plot the Diestel-Leader graph... I'm clueless on this one, and it's been too many years since I last manipulated graphs/trees structures.

**Could anyone give me a helping hand please ?**

*P.S. :* I took [python](/questions/tagged/python) as an example, but I am not restrincting myself to any particular language, especially if one allows for an easier implementation !

---

## Update

I think I made up a simple way to represent elements of the tree *T<sub>p</sub>* that also takes the height function into account. A picture being worth much more than words, here it is :

[image]

I circled the origin vertex *o*∈*T<sub>p</sub>*. In my picture, I took *p*=3 and *R*=3. I start with the (only) vertex *x* distant *R* from *o* and whose height is *h*(*x*)=-*R*. I label it `""`, and I append a `"0"`, a `"1"` or a `"2"` to the end of a string representing a vertex to represent its children.

The height of a vertex *x* represented by a string of length *L* is given by the relation *h*(*x*)=*L*-*R*. This may be convenient when trying to generate *DL*(*p*,*q*). <s>However, the catch is I wasn't able to implement an algorithm to generate the ball of radius *R* in the tree by this method... I tried a recursive algorithm, but I didn't see what to pass as arguments...</s>

Now, I have managed to implement the recursion to generate the ball of radius *R* in *T<sub>p</sub>* ! Here is how it looks (the exact same as the hand-drawn picture) :

[image]

My code for this is the following :

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def T(p,R):
    T = GraphVisualization()
    def addChildren(vertex,gen):
        if(gen>0):
            for k in range(p):
                T.addEdge(vertex,vertex+str(k))
                addChildren(vertex+str(k),gen-1)
    o = R*str(p-1)
    addChildren(o,R)
    for k in range(1,R+1):
        addChildren(o[:(R-k)],R-k)
    T.addEdge("0",str(p-1))
    T.visualize()
```

Note that this is *very* far from being optimal, as I generate several edges a lot of times. But I don't mind if the code is not optimized, I just want it working to visualize the balls !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was very close to finishing ! It boiled down to writing the definition of the edge set for the Diestel-Leader graph :

*E*[*DL*(*p*,*q*)]={(*e<sub>1</sub>*,*e<sub>2</sub>*)∈*E*[*T<sub>p</sub>*]×*E*[*T<sub>q</sub>*] : *h*(*i*(*e<sub>1</sub>*))+*h*'(*i*(*e<sub>2</sub>*))=*h*(*t*(*e<sub>1</sub>*))+*h*'(*t*(*e<sub>2</sub>*))=0}

with *i*(*e*) denoting the initial vertex of the edge *e* and *t*(*e*) the terminal edge. Therefore, I simply looped through all edges of both trees and checked for that condition :

```
def height(v,R):
    if(v=="0"): return -R
    return len(v)-R

def DL(p,q,R):
    Tp = T(p,R)
    Tq = T(q,R)
    G = GraphVisualization()
    for e1 in Tp.visual:
        for e2 in Tq.visual:
            ie1, te1 = e1[1], e1[0]
            ie2, te2 = e2[0], e2[1]
            if(height(ie1,R)+height(ie2,R)==0 and height(te1,R)+height(te2,R)==0):
                G.addEdge(ie1+","+ie2,te1+","+te2)
    G.visualize()
```

Vertices in the Diestel-Leader graph `G` are represented by strings of the form `"XXX,YYY"`, with `"XXX"` being the string representing a vertex in *T<sub>p</sub>* and `"YYY"` being the string representing a vertex in *T<sub>q</sub>*.

Here is the picture of the ball of radius 2 in *DL*(2,3) (centered at `"11,22"`) :

[image]